# How can i provide a custom server ip rather than the localhost in flask

Tags: flask

I like to redirect to a url for sending the confirmation mail, using **url_for** method

```
url_for('bun.confirm_email', token=token, mailid=email, _external=True)
```

Here **bun** is the name of the blueprint. Since am running the server on the localhost - the url is generated as 127.0.0.1. All my requests to 0.0.0.0 has been proxy forwarded by nginx to  localhost, I cannot run the flask server on 0.0.0.0.

Is there a work around where i can get the actual server IP for redirect using blueprint, without actually running the server on 0.0.0.0

Comment: You might want to look into ip addresses first,  like https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

Comment: Then how do i set the static path of blueprint as 0.0.0.0:8000/blueprint_path, while still running my server on localhost

Comment: What did you pass host param in flask app run?

Comment: My host will be 127.0.0.1 @SrikanthChekuri

Comment: You can explicitly bass the host value during app instance creation. Pass 0.0.0.0 there and url_for uses the same application context which solves your problem.

Comment: But i don't want anyone external to access my applications - running the host as 0.0.0.0 means I expose my application